# float' object has no attribute 'split' python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am newbie with Python. i have this Python code to split Columns from csv array:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

#get data from traffic
name_regex = r"(?<=(\'name\': ))[^,]*(?=,)"
medium_regex = r"(?<=(\'medium\': ))[^,]*(?=,)"
source_regex = r"(?<=(\'source\': ))[^,]*(?=})"

def get_name(x):
    return [re.search(name_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]
def get_medium(x):
    return [re.search(medium_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]
def get_source(x):
    return [re.search(source_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]

df["traffic_name"] = df["traffic"].apply(get_name)
df["traffic_medium"] = df["traffic"].apply(get_medium)
df["traffic_source"] = df["traffic"].apply(get_source)
del df["traffic"]

final_df = df.explode(["traffic_name", "traffic_medium", "traffic_source"])

print(final_df)

final_df.to_csv("traffic.csv")
```

this is my csv data:

```
,traffic_source
0,"{'name': '(test1)', 'medium': '(no1)', 'source': '(yes)'}"
1,
2,"{'name': '(test1)', 'medium': 'no2', 'source': 'yes1'}"
3,
4,"{'name': '(test2)', 'medium': 'no3', 'source': 'yes'}"
```

when i run the python code , there is an Error. Can you please help?
Thank you

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15228\2852501840.py in get_name(x)
     12 
     13 def get_name(x):
---> 14     return [re.search(name_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]
     15 def get_medium(x):
     16     return [re.search(medium_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: use str() : ... for line in str(x).split("\n")]

Answer (score 1):

The first column in your CSV file is a number (being treated as a float). Numbers cannot be split.

Additionally, your CSV data looks like it's storing JSON in the second column. Rather than writing regular expressions, just decode the string using the [json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because `Pandas` treat the first and third rows of the `traffic` column (There is no value, which means nan) as a `float`, you can remove `float` rows using:

```
df=df[df['traffic'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```

Whole solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import re

#I use this to regenerate your CSV
CSV=StringIO("""
,traffic
0,"{'name': '(test1)', 'medium': '(no1)', 'source': '(yes)'}"
1,
2,"{'name': '(test1)', 'medium': 'no2', 'source': 'yes1'}"
3,
4,"{'name': '(test2)', 'medium': 'no3', 'source': 'yes'}"
""")


df = pd.read_csv(CSV, sep=",")


name_regex = r"(?<=(\'name\': ))[^,]*(?=,)"
medium_regex = r"(?<=(\'medium\': ))[^,]*(?=,)"
source_regex = r"(?<=(\'source\': ))[^,]*(?=})"

def get_name(x):
  return [re.search(name_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]
def get_medium(x):
      return [re.search(medium_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]
def get_source(x):
      return [re.search(source_regex, line).group().replace("'", "") for line in x.split("\n")]


df=df[df['traffic'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))] 

df["traffic_name"] =   df["traffic"].apply(get_name)
df["traffic_medium"] = df["traffic"].apply(get_medium)
df["traffic_source"] = df["traffic"].apply(get_source)
del df["traffic"]

final_df = df.explode(["traffic_name", "traffic_medium", "traffic_source"])

print(final_df)

final_df.to_csv("traffic.csv")
```